# Better routes practice to return JSON with given params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get the JSON result by `Expected request URL`. How could I do it?

**Current request URL:**

http://localhost:3000/research/demo/customer/12,13/history.json

**Expected request URL:**

http://localhost:3000/research/demo/customer/history/12,13

**Current routes:**

```
namespace :research do
  namespace :demo do
    get 'customer/:items/history.json' => "customer#history"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  namespace :research do
    namespace :demo do
      get 'customer/history/*items' => "customer#history"
    end
  end
```

Every request is rendered as html or json or xml depending on request format

Comment: but the `items` are separated by `commas` , did u mean I shuold send the params in this way `1,3,4523,34.json` it look ugly ? any better suggestion ? thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer added *items so now you can call url as customer/history/1/2/3/4..